What is the secret to setting up a nextjs/next-auth app to log the user into instagram so the app has access to her instagram picture data?
My [...next-auth].js works fine for Credentials and Dropbox providers, which I worked on first, but the app fails instantly with Instagram login. My app works fine with a hard-coded user for the Instagram piece, but I need to open it up to multiple users, so each user has to be challenged with an instagram login at some point.
Does anyone have an Instagram provider setup that they would care to share?
this is what I have currently:
  InstagramProvider({
    clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.INSTSAGRAM_SECRET,
    authorization: {
      params: {
        scopes: "user_profile user_media",
        authorizationUrl: "https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
        tokenUrl: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
      },



callbacks: {
  jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
    token.user = user;
    console.log("token: ", token);
    if (account?.provider === "instagram") {
      token.InstagramAccessToken = account.access_token;
      token.InstagramRefreshToken = account.refreshToken;
      token.InstagramAccessTokenExpires =
        Date.now() + (account.expires_in as number) * 1000;
    } else if (account?.provider === "dropbox") {
      token.DropBoxAccessToken = account.access_token;
      token.DropBoxRefreshToken = account.refreshToken;
      token.DropBoxAccessTokenExpires =
        Date.now() + (account.expires_in as number) * 1000;
    }

